# Spyder plugins (spyder-autopep8)

Tags: python, plugins, spyder

So I'm trying to install the spyder-autopep8 plugin from here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-autopep8

I downloaded and unzipped it and ran `python setup.py install` as instructed. (This is inside my ../.spyder-py3/plugins folder)

My question is how do I use this inside Spyder? The instructions from the README (link above) says to hit F8 or go to `Source > Run autopep8 code autoformatting`. But right now, the default F8 for me is `Source > Run static code analysis`.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

just stumbled upon the very same problem...

i got it working by first installing new spyder via pip and then
installing autopep8 directly from the git repository via:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-autopep8.git
```

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder developer here*) I'm sorry but (in April/2017) `spyder-autopep8` is not ready to be used. We'll try make a formal release of this plugin in the following months, so that it can be installed using `pip` or `conda`.

Comment: is it working now ? I am still not able to use autopep8 on spyder

Comment: Thanks Carlos for a response. Is there a way for spyder 3.1.4 to autocomplete the code ?

Comment: I have just tried and it worked fine for me. I cloned the repo into my plugins dir, and moved the `spyder_autopep8` folder one level up. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I moved the spyder_autopep8 folder to the plugins dir. Now shift+f8 is working in spyder,.