# installing spyder_autopep8 on spyder 4 and getting it to work

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm having trouble installing `spyder_autopep8` package/plugin to the newly released spyder 4 and getting it to work.

I've tried the these solutions:
 [How to use autopep8 to format code in Spyder / Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169488/how-to-use-autopep8-to-format-code-in-spyder-anaconda)
, [Spyder plugins (spyder-autopep8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222138/spyder-plugins-spyder-autopep8)

but they seems to work only in spyder `3.3.X`.
There are some interesting new linting tools in spyder 4 but i couldn't find a tool that does what `spyder_autopep8` do, i.e., formats the code as best it can to `PEP8`.

This really helps the readability of my code.
Maybe Spyder developers can shed light on this matter ?

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That plugin is not maintained anymore and it only works with Spyder **3.3.6**.

That's because we added support to format code with Autopep8 and Black in Spyder **4.2.0**, released in November 2020.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work on Spyder, It is a very useful and effective tool in my scientific work.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thanks for all the work with Spyder, version 4 is great. Any progress with the autopep8 stuff?

Comment: @mathisfun, thanks for your kind words! There's no progress yet, but I hope to have it ready by the end of March.

Comment: Can vouch that it works great in Spyder 4.2.  `preferences→completion and linting→code style and formatting→ code formatting →autoformat files on save`

Answer (score 2):

According to this issue on github https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-autopep8/issues/10 autopep8 is supported since spyder 4.2.0